# empty path name of image while uploading

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to upload image, but it is showing blank `path name` of image and not uploading the image.

I am getting this array when I var_dump my file input.

```
array (size=2)
'worker' => string 'fileUpload' (length=10)
'image' => 
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'download (1).jpg' (length=16)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
  private 'size' => int 0
  private 'error' => int 6
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '' (length=0)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string '' (length=0)
```

I have also tried images with different size. Not getting any clue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: LOOK AT THE `'error'` Does that give you a smallest hint at what might be wrong. If not here is another clue [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: how can I print that `error`?

Comment: that is showing `Missing a temporary folder`

Comment: From the manual `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder.`

Comment: is this any issue with server end?

Comment: Yes definitely its a server end issue.

Comment: How can I solve this, I do not have much knowledge of server

Comment: Is the server yours or are you using hosted server

Comment: I am using hosted server (shared hosting)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88600/discussion-between-anshul-mishra-and-riggsfolly).